# Suggestions on how to go about a simple example displaying scala's multiprocessor capabilities

Tags: scala, multiprocessing

So i have completed the coursera course on scala and have taken it upon myself to do a small POC showing  off the multiprocessor capabilities of scala.

i am looking at creating a very small example where a application can launch multiple tasks(each task will do some network related queries etc) and i can show the usage of multiple cores as well. 
Also there will be a thread that will listen on a specific port of a machine and spawn tasks based on what information it receives there.

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this kind of a problem? 
I don't want to use AKKA now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallel collections are perhaps the least-effort way to make use of multiple processors in Scala. It naturally leads into how best to organise one's code and data to take advantage of the parallel operations, and more importantly what *doesn't* get faster.

As a more concrete problem, suppose you have read a CSV file (or XML document, or whatever) and want to parse the data. If the records have already been split into a collection such as a `List[String]`, you can then do `.par` to create a parallel List, and then a subsequent `.map` will use all cores where possible. The resulting `List[whatever]` will retain the same ordering even though the operations were not executed sequentially. Consider summing the values on each line:

```
val in: List[String] = ...
val out = in.par.map { line =>
    val cols = line split ','
    cols.map(_.toInt).sum
}
```

So an `in` of `List("1,2,3", "4,5,6")` would result in an `out` of `List(6, 15)`, as it would without the `.par`. but it'll run across multiple cores. Whether it's *faster* is another matter, since there is overhead in using parallel collections that likely makes a trivial example such as this *slower*. You will want to experiment to see where parallel collections are a benefit for your use cases.

There is a more extensive discussion and documentation of parallel collections at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But i am looking for a example that uses actors/channels etc.

Comment: You said "I don't want to use AKKA now" which is why I didn't suggest the actor route.

Comment: Akka is the de facto Scala actor library, so you should be looking at that. Scala's old actor library `scala.actor` is discussed at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors.html which states "NOTE: In Scala 2.10 the Actors library is deprecated and will be removed in future Scala releases" and it is indeed not part of Scala 2.11.

Comment: Oh i did not know that . Thanks for the information. Can you guide me to some samples of using actors and channels. i would like to explore that path for my POC.

Comment: Please look at the documentation at http://akka.io/. The documentation is extensive and fairly good, although the examples can be so-so. If you continue to have problems, please start a new question rather than add more comments here.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [sleeping barber problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem)? You could implement it in a distributed manner over the network, with the barber(s)' spawning service listening on one port and the customers spawning and requesting the barber(s) services over the network.

I think that would be vast and interesting enough while not being impossible.

Then you can build on it to expand it as much as you want, such as adding specialized barbers for different things (hair cut or shaving) and down from there. Sky (or, better, thread's no. cap) is the limit!